# How to AirPlay audio to multiple AirPlay devices from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, airplay, mpvolumeview

Normally only one AirPlay device is selectable in the `MPVolumeView` when playing audio. However it seems that it is possible to AirPlay to multiple devices since [Whaale iOS app](http://www.whaale.com/index.php/component/k2/item/11-what-is-whaale) does. How might the Whaale app stream to multiple devices?

(I don't care if it uses undocumented APIs, this isn't for App Store purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

This is WHAALE speaking.

There is no API on iOS to do multiroom playback with AirPlay, as you noticed.

We had to implement it from scratch and it took a while.

We have no public API to offer to you.